# Sort CSV powershell script delete duplicate, keep the one with a special value in 3rd column

Tags: powershell, csv, sorting, unique

How do I delete double entriys in a csv by one column and leave the one with one special value in one of the columns?

Example: I got a csv with

Name;Employeenumber;Accessrights

Max;123456;ReadOnly

Berta;133556;Write

Jhonny;161771;ReadOnly

Max;123456;Write

I want to end up with:

Name;Employeenumber;Accessrights

Max;123456;Write

Berta;133556;Write

Jhonny;161771;ReadOnly

I tried by Get-Content Select-Object -unique, but that does not solve the problem that it should only keep the ones with the value "write" at the property Accessrights.
So I have no clue at all

Comment: When you crosspost the same question at the same time to different forums you should at least post links to the other forums along with your question to avoid people willing to help you making their work twice or more.Thanks  [PowerShell.org - Cleanup CSV by values similar values and keep one special](https://forums.powershell.org/t/cleanup-csv-by-values-similar-values-and-keep-one-special/21268)

Comment: Please format your question properly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of sorting and grouping ....

```
@'
Name;Employeenumber;Accessrights
Max;123456;ReadOnly
Berta;133556;Write
Jhonny;161771;ReadOnly
Max;123456;Write
'@ |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' |
        Sort-Object -Property Name, Accessrights -Descending |
            Group-Object -Property Name |
                ForEach-Object {
                    $_.Group[0]
                }
```